# Generic inheritance in C#: Cannot implicitly convert type 'MyWidget' to 'IWidget'

Tags: c#, generics, inheritance

I'm having a problem setting up inheritance with generics.

In essence what I want to do is have a generic interface that itself accepts an interface.  the tricky part is that "inner" interface could have a more specific interface layered on top of it.

Here is a representative sample of the structure that I'm trying to build:

```
public interface IThing  { }

public interface IMoreSpecificThing : IThing  {  }

public interface IWidget<T> where T : IThing  {  }

public class MySpecificThing : IMoreSpecificThing { }

public class MyWidget : IWidget<MySpecificThing> { }

public class MyClass
{
    public IWidget<IThing> MyProperty { get; set; }

    public MyClass()
    {
        MyProperty = new MyWidget();
    }
}
```

The problem is that when I assign MyWidget to MyProperty, I receive the following error:

> Cannot implicitly convert type `'MyWidget'` to `'IWidget<IThing>'`. An
>   explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

What am I doing wrong, and is there a way to do this properly?

Comment: @Michael this will crash.

Comment: @SargeBorsch Yes, I was a bit quick with the comment.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This would require making your interface covariant:

```
public interface IWidget<out T> where T : IThing  {  }
```

For details, see [Covariance and Contravariance in Generics](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd799517.aspx).  Note that this does put restrictions on the interface, mainly:

> All the type parameters of these interfaces are covariant, so the type parameters are used only for the return types of the members.

Comment: Thank you very much for the snappy and accurate response.  And bonus points for the link... very informative.